# app store purchases disappeared

Tags: ipad

So before about three years ago i had downloaded the apps; classic angry birds,tiny wings, and the full fruitninja using my app store account. But now ever since i bought a ipad mini, it doesnt show these record of purchased apps or even display these apps in the appstore when i type up their names.

Is there a way to work around this and restore my purchases and keep these paid apps?

Comment: When you set up your iPad mini did you use your existing Apple Id or create a new one? App purchases are tied to your Id, so if you used the same one as before your apps should carry over.

Comment: Im pretty sure i used the same app store id

Answer (score 1):

Purchases as default never disappear. If you can't open via App Store I suggest opening safari and search for "Angry Birds iTunes" or any other relevant app. When you open the page from safari, the iTunes App will open by default and you will be able to download the app.